# chart js height 100%

Tags: css, charts, chart.js

I have a problem with the height of the graph, I cannot set the height to 100%, find the image of my two graphs below
[image]

here are the options of the graph

```
type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: chartdata,
            options:{
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                aspectRatio: 1,
                animation: false,
                scaleSteps: 10,
                legend:{
                    display: false,
                },
                showAllTooltips: true,
                tooltips:{
                    enabled: false,
                },
                layout:{
                    padding:{
                        right: 70,
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        position: 'top',
                        gridLines: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Nombre de mouvement par outil',
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            stepSize: 1,
                        },
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        barPercentage:0.9,
                        categoryPercentage:1,
                        gridLines: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Identifiants outils',
                        },
                    }],
                },
```

I looked at all the possible options I can't do it

Comment: What do you mean, it seems like both charts use the max height they can use, only the right one can use a bit less since you want a scale title

Comment: the columns are stacked one after the other, there is no space between each column see img

Comment: help me plz impossible to adapt the window to my graph despite all the options activated, you don't want to